# Quelle est l'orthographe du gentilé de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon ?

Tags: france, gentilés

L'article Wikipédia donne « Saint-Pierrais ou Miquelonais » comme gentilé des habitants de [Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon) ; une note indique que « en l'absence de gentilé établi, on désigne les habitants du département par leur appartenance communale [archive], ce qui correspond aussi aux îles principales de l'archipel » (Wikipédia). Wiktionnaire donne le deuxième avec deux *n* : « [Miquelonnais(e)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Miquelonnais) ».

- Peut-on confirmer l'orthographe en s'appuyant sur une source crédible ?
- Peut-on indiquer tous les « gentilés des communes » de cette
  communauté autres que « Saint-Pierrais ou Miquelonais/Miquelonnais »,
  le cas échéant ?

Answer (score 1):

*Autour des mots* de Georges Morell (Éditions des journaux officiels, 2005, p. 136), donne *Saint-Pierrais* seulement. Tout ce qu'il y a de plus officiel, donc.